# Memset memory overflow

Tags: c++, qt, memory

```
memset(outsideWallHeightMap, 0, sizeof(outsideWallHeightMap[0][0]) * CHUNK_SIZE_MULT * ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE_MULT);


quint8 outsideWallHeightMap[INSIDE_ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE_MULT][CHUNK_SIZE_MULT];

#define ITEM_MAP_SIZE 128
#define CHUNK_SIZE 8
#define CHUNK_SIZE_MULT (CHUNK_SIZE*CHUNK_SIZE)

#define INSIDE_ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE (INSIDE_ITEM_MAP_SIZE/CHUNK_SIZE)

#define INSIDE_ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE_MULT (INSIDE_ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE*INSIDE_ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE)
```

I have no idea why this totally corrupts my memory! I had troubles before with quint8, I'm hoping it's not that..

Any insight would be great!

Comment: INSIDE_ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE_MULT does not appear as being defined in your sample code

Comment: Updated. I changed all quint8 to quint16, no change either.

Comment: Got it, I swapped inside and outside! So stupid.. Was going over a revision must've screwed that up.

Comment: How do you know that it "totally corrupts your memory"?  Can you provide a minimal test-case?

Comment: *Aside*: prefer `memset(outsideWallHeightMap, 0, sizeof outsideWallHeightMap)` to what you have. [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: I tried sizeof array before, but thought it might've been the cause so changed it. Good to hear that could never be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

`memset(outsideWallHeightMap, 0, sizeof(outsideWallHeightMap[0][0]) * CHUNK_SIZE_MULT *`**INSIDE_ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE_MULT**`));`

or easier

```
memset(outsideWallHeightMap, 0, sizeof(outsideWallHeightMap));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also initialize everything to 0 this way:

```
quint8 outsideWallHeightMap[INSIDE_ITEM_CHUNK_SIZE_MULT][CHUNK_SIZE_MULT] = {{0}};
```